# Does operating system thread scheduling factor in to the decision to use std::sync::Mutex vs tokio::sync::Mutex?

Tags: rust, mutex, rust-tokio

The [`tokio::sync::mutex` documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html) mentions the following:

> Contrary to popular belief, it is ok and often preferred to use the ordinary Mutex from the standard library in asynchronous code.

This comment is worked out in a bit more detail by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840831/23196665) SO answer:

> - If you need to hold the lock over an .await call, use an asynchronous mutex. The compiler will usually reject this anyway when using thread-safe futures since most synchronous mutex locks can't be sent to another thread.
> - If your lock is contentious (i.e. if you expect the mutex to already be locked when you want it), you should use an asynchronous mutex. This can happen when synchronizing multiple tasks into a pool or bounded queue.
> - If you have complicated and/or computationally-heavy updates, those should probably be moved to a blocking pool anyway where you'd use a synchronous mutex.

This seems to paint a complete picture in case the single-threaded tokio runtime is used. However, if one uses the multi-threaded runtime, a situation could arise where a task A on OS thread 1 holds a synchronous mutex and has its thread pre-empted by the operating system, at which point a task B on thread 2 might be scheduled and waste cycles trying to acquire the mutex. This would not be an issue with tokio mutexes, since task B would call `await` and could be replaced with a different task.

Why is this potential disadvantage of synchronous mutexes not mentioned more often?
Is this source of overhead generally insignificant compared to the overhead of using asynchronous mutexes?

Comment: This is why we have the second point ("If your lock is contentious ...").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make a difference. If your lock is not contentious and not held for long, then it is unlikely to be in this scenario anyway and a synchronous mutex would generally yield better performance overall compared to an asynchronous mutex even if this does happen occasionally.

More:

I think one key thing to realize is that the OS reschedules threads *all the time*. Even with no mutexes involved, your asynchronous tasks are constantly being micro-paused anyway because the OS is trying to juggle hundreds or thousands of threads fighting over a handful of logical threads. So if a thread with a lock is paused, another thread desiring the lock will effectively be paused as well, but that is not far off from what happens anyway.

Another factor to consider is that the `std::sync::Mutex` is backed by OS primitive locking calls and not simply in user-space AFAIK. This means that even if the thread is preempted, the OS knows both that the thread has progress that it wants to make and that it holds a lock. And if another thread becomes blocked by that same lock, the OS is aware of that. This can affect the OS's scheduling to give the lock holding thread higher priority to get going again. This lessens the impact of contentious threads when using `std::sync::Mutex`.

Above all, you should always benchmark to see if it makes a difference in your use-case.

Comment: Oh, the `Mutex` implementation being backed by the OS is not something I had thought about. Thanks!